# How to get information about process in Linux

Tags: linux, process

How can I get **process statistics from the kernel** and return the buf as the following?

> number of processes : ticks_user : ticks_system : ticks_interrupt : cpuseconds : procsizes : resident segment sizes

I found some information in `/proc/[pid]/stat`, but there is no data about **ticks system, ticks_interrupt, and cpusecond**.

Where can I find information about these?

Any pointers to API or documentation will be helpful.

Comment: I did not fully understand your last line? You want a C program? Or you just want documentation or information?

Comment: information or documentation about ticks system, ticks_interrupt, cpusecond. I don't know where I am get information about ticks system, ticks_interrupt, cpusecond. Sorry for the error.

Comment: Edited your question. Not a problem. Just make sure you tell people here what exactly you want, they will help you out. Hopefully some linux people will come by =)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ps ax
top
htop
```

for the start, read the manpage, and for top/htop press  <kbd>h</kbd> to get a help screen  <kbd>q</kbd>  to quit;

However, none of the manpages mentions ticks - what is it?

Answer (score 1):

You may can give [vmstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmstat) a try. It is not in ticks, but why do you need ticks?

```
CPU
   These are percentages of total CPU time.
   us: Time spent running non-kernel code. (user time, including nice time)
   sy: Time spent running kernel code. (system time)
   id: Time spent idle. Prior to Linux 2.5.41, this includes I/O-wait time.
   wa: Time spent waiting for I/O. Prior to Linux 2.5.41, included in idle.
   st: Time stolen from a virtual machine. Prior to Linux 2.6.11, unknown.
```

What are you planing to do with this information?

Sometimes it may also to [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) through the kernel sources, trying your buzzwords.

Comment: Tnanks. I am parse /proc/[pid]/stat and find needed my data.

Comment: sscanf(proc_buf, "%*d %*s %*s %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %d %d %d %*d %*d %*d %*d %d", &cpu_uticks, &cpu_sticks, &cpu_iticks, &i);   - proc_buf is /proc/[pid]/stat

Comment: You may improve the reliability of your code by using a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) instead of the brute force sscanf. If you have the possibility to use [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) give it a try.